# How to fetch sql php with condition or merge fetch with condition?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called `links` with columns called `link` `link2` `link3` and `score`
I want to always fetch `link` , but fetch `link2` only if `score` is >= 100 . and fetch `link3` only if `score` is >= 200. then put all these results in one row to read it in one row.
see my script (that is not loading at all)

```
    $sql = "SELECT link, link2, link3, score FROM links WHERE useron=1";
$liste = array('link');
$liste2 = array ('link2');
$liste3 = array ('link3');
if ( $liste2['score'] >= 100 && < 200 ) {
$liste[] = 'link2';
if ( $liste3['score'] >= 200 )
$liste[] = 'link3';

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['link'] . "\n"; 
        }
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the following:

```
SELECT link, 
       CASE
           WHEN score >= 100 THEN link2
           ELSE ''
       END as link2, 
       CASE
           WHEN score >= 200 THEN link3
           ELSE ''
       END as link3, 
       score
FROM links
WHERE useron = 1
```

and then fetch all rows and display all non-empty link.

Comment: this is what i did Lajos Arpad , i mean i cannot see the result as my page is not loading at all...

Comment: @Specimenx33 you didn't do this exact thing, you have done this logic on PHP level, but more importantly, you get an error somewhere, so you will need to give us more information about the actual error that you get.

Comment: i'm sorry @Lajos Arpad i'm new to php and this is the last step of my project to finalize.
the error is simply error 500 (this page is not loading) when i go to the url.
what a did wrong about your help post please? i'm trying to get this working but more importantly i want to learn

Comment: @Specimenx33 500 means internal server error. You will need to check the server logs to find out what the exact error is.

Comment: my page is working when i only echo link from one basic sql request.
the error is more likely about my syntax on that part i think but i dont see where...

Comment: @Specimenx33 this line is certainly a bug if ( $liste2['score'] >= 100 && < 200 ) { because $liste does not have a 'score' item at that point. You seem to assume that the query was executed, but it's not. You will need to move this logic into the while cycle and use $row['score'], however, you will really need to check the server error logs. If you learn that now, you save yourself from lots of future troubles.